# document.getElementById("toai").innerHTML = document.getElementById("toai").value

Tags: javascript

```
<script>
function toai()
{
var Fr_amt_invt  = document.getElementById("Fr_amt_invt").value;
var Re_amt_invt  = document.getElementById("Re_amt_invt").value;
var totaltoai = +Fr_amt_invt + +Re_amt_invt;
document.getElementById("toai").innerHTML=+totaltoai;
}

</script>
```

function toai() result is in .innerHTML i want result in .value format so that it use in form input.

Comment: There is no such thing as a "value format" (not sure what you mean by that). Whether to use `.innerHTML` or `.value` depends on the element you are working with. So, what element is `#toai`? Also,  `parseFloat` is supposed to be used on *strings*, not *numbers*.

Comment: `totaltoai = parseFloat(totaltoai)` is redundant. Adding two numbers must result in a number (there are no integer or float types in ECMAscript, only number).

Comment: Thanks for reply. I know sir my english is very bad & my coding is also very bad. programming is not my field i am an accountant. Due to my interest in programming or for my routine work doing easily i try to make some small app. related to my work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of doing `document.getElementById("toai").innerHTML=+totaltoai;` in the `toai()`function you can `return` the value.

```
<script>
function toai()
{
var Fr_amt_invt  = document.getElementById("Fr_amt_invt").value;
var Re_amt_invt  = document.getElementById("Re_amt_invt").value;
Fr_amt_invt = parseFloat(Fr_amt_invt);
Re_amt_invt = parseFloat(Re_amt_invt);
var totaltoai = (Fr_amt_invt + Re_amt_invt);
totaltoai = parseFloat(totaltoai);
//document.getElementById("toai").innerHTML=+totaltoai; // delete this
return totaltoai;
}
```

Then you can do `document.getElementById('some-inputs-id').value = toai();`

Comment: Thanks for reply sir. I am not a programmer so please write code in detail.